# keyboard keyisdown is not activating

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to make my paddle move up and down when I press the d and a buttons.
When i press the d and a buttons nothing happens at all... they just sit there.....
anyway the code is below if you know please tell me. thanks
I am aware the indenting is wrong i had to change if for this post:)

```
  window_width = 580
   window_height = 420

   playerScore = 0
        enemyScore = 0

   pSpeed = 200

       player1Y = 100
    player2Y = -20




   function love.load()

  love.window.setMode(window_width, window_height)

   end

    function love.draw()
      love.graphics.printf('hello pong', 0, window_height / 2 - 6, window_width, 'center')
     love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 500, player1Y , 10, 50)




   love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 40, 220, 10, 50)

   love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 100, 230, 7, 5)


 end
 function update(dt)

if love.keyboard.isDown('d') then                     
   player1Y = player1Y + pSpeed * dt
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('a') then               
     player1Y = player1Y + -pSpeed * dt
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pSpeed = 10` instead of 200, so your rectangles aren't jumping beyond window_height in 2 steps.
And [change colors](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.setColor) for each rectangle, so it's easier to see what's happening.

```
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor( 0, 0, 0 )  --  black
    love.graphics.printf( 'hello pong', 0, window_height /2 -6, window_width, 'center' )

    love.graphics.setColor( 1, 0, 0 )  --  red
    love.graphics.rectangle( "fill", 500, player1Y, 10, 50 )

    love.graphics.setColor( 0, 1, 0 )  --  green
    love.graphics.rectangle( "fill", 40, 220, 10, 50 )

    love.graphics.setColor( 0, 0, 1 )  --  blue
    love.graphics.rectangle( "fill", 100, 230, 7, 5 )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write "love.update(dt)" instead of writing only "update(dt)". I tried changing that and it worked! Also, indenting does not affect the way your code works in Lua, but it does massively improve readability.